# Tangent bundle of an almost complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(X,J)$ be an almost complex manifold with dimension $2n$. Then the tangent bundle $TX$ can trivially be made an $n$ dimensional complex vector space along each fibre. But how can I find a smooth trivialization (or a smooth local frame) of $TX$ so that it can be made a rank $n$ smooth complex vector bundle?

Comment: Pick the first (local) nonvanishing vector field. Hit it with J; that's your second. Find a new vector field (locally) linearly independent from the previous two. Hit it with J. Keep going until you're done.

Comment: How would you choose the third vector field that is linearly independent from  the first two? Again, fiberwise it is trivial. But why the vector field would be smooth in this case?

Comment: Pick it at the basepoint and choose any smooth local extension. Then, close enough to the basepoint, it will still be linearly independent of the others by continuity.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!!